# How do you easily sync up lyrics to a song audio file?

Tags: python, synchronization, speech-recognition

I have this song: more specifically, [Last Name by Carrie Underwood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f27zNlmRMWU). I have the audio of the song and the lyrics for it, but what is the best possible way to get the timestamps of when each lyric is said?

I've tried using Aeneas, `os.system('python -m aeneas.tools.execute_task audio.mp3 text1.txt "task_language=eng|is_text_type=subtitles|os_task_file_format=json" timing.json')`, but many of the timestamps are incorrect. Places like Musixmatch or Megalobiz don't have the song (among others that I need) in their database, and most other Automatic Lyric Alignment websites aren't online or don't connect to Python well to my knowledge. Is there a better way to do this?